# Why I can't scan codes of extra keys for Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 (usb) via evtest?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

sudo evtest output:

```
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Power Button
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event2:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event3:  ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse
/dev/input/event4:  VirtualBox USB Tablet
/dev/input/event5:  VirtualBox mouse integration
```

My setup:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I would like to have zoom slider and prev/next buttons working.

Does anybody manage to get this work on Xubuntu?